# creating a stored procedure with join?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

When creating stored procedures and trying to get an output for a join and group, do I need to write the code in another query?  When I run the code it says the procedure already exists.  So I am not sure how to get the correct input while creating a procedure.

The question:  Create a stored procedure called MentoredStudents which will display student first and last names. Only students who are being mentored are to be selected. Sort the output by student last name, then first name.

The table student contains: firstname, lastname, studentno

The table Student_Professor contains column mentor ('1' being mentored 0 not), studentno

My query

```
    DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE MentoredStudents()
BEGIN
SELECT firstname, lastname 
FROM lab10.student s;
END //
DELIMITER ;
SELECT firstname, lastname
FROM lab10.student s
JOIN lab10.student_professor sp
ON s.studentno = sp.studentno
AND sp.mentor = 1
GROUP BY s.lastname, s.firstname;
```

Comment: Move the "END" keyword at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confused since you've started by creating a stored procedure, but closed that before creating a SELECT that starts well, but ends badly.

What you want is

```
delimiter //
create procedure mentoredStudents()
Begin
SELECT S.firstname, S.lastname from lab10.student S 
    join lab10.student_professor SP 
    on (S.studentno = SP.studentno) 
    where SP.mentored = 1
    order by S.lastname, S.firstname;
END //
Delimiter ;

call mentoredStudents();
```

Comment: The issue is that it says the created procedure already exists and will not output anything. would i create a new query in this case?

Comment: @Steve Delete the existing procedure with [DROP PROCEDURE...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-procedure.html)